# Why isn't my model learning?

Tags: keras

```
import numpy as np
from keras.datasets import cifar10
from keras.layers import Dense, Activation
from keras.optimizers import SGD
from keras.utils import np_utils
from keras import backend as k
from keras.models import Sequential

(Xtr,Ytr),(Xte,Yte)=cifar10.load_data()

Xtr = Xtr.astype('float32')
Xte = Xte.astype('float32')

Xtr = Xtr.reshape(50000, 3072)
Xte = Xte.reshape(10000, 3072)

Ytr = np_utils.to_categorical(Ytr, 10)
Yte = np_utils.to_categorical(Yte, 10)

model=Sequential()
model.add(Dense(100, input_shape=Xtr.shape[1:]))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dense(10))
model.add(Activation('softmax'))

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer="sgd", metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(Xtr, Ytr, batch_size=200, epochs=30, shuffle=True,verbose=1)

scores = model.evaluate(Xte, Yte, verbose=0)
print("Accuracy: %.2f%%" % (scores[1] * 100))
```

And the result:

[image]

I am trying to creat a pretty basic 2 layer NN on cifar-10. I know that the data is not preprocessed. But that can't be the reason for learning nothing. Where am I making the mistake?

Comment: Instead of photos, give your code so that is easily reproducible and consequently people can help you quickly. At least this is a better practice.

Comment: Done.............

Comment: Much better. Great

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll go through an example that will help you get started. It should get approximately 50% accuracy.

So I keep the code the same as yours for loading the data. The only difference is that I normalize the data to lie between 0 and 1. This is usually recommended to bound the weights more tightly.

```
import numpy as np
from keras.datasets import cifar10
from keras.layers import Dense, Activation
from keras.optimizers import SGD
from keras.utils import np_utils
from keras import backend as k
from keras.models import Sequential
import keras
from keras.datasets import mnist
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Flatten
from keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D
from keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint
from keras.models import model_from_json
from keras import backend as K

(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test)=cifar10.load_data()
```

> Downloading data from https://www.cs.toronto.edu/~kriz/cifar-10-python.tar.gz 
> 170500096/170498071 [==============================] - 71s 0us/step

```
(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test)=cifar10.load_data()

x_train = x_train.astype('float32') / 255.
x_test = x_test.astype('float32') / 255.

x_train = x_train.reshape(50000, 3072)
x_test = x_test.reshape(10000, 3072)

# The known number of output classes.
num_classes = 10

# Channels go last for TensorFlow backend
x_train_reshaped = x_train.reshape(x_train.shape[0], x_train.shape[1],)
x_test_reshaped = x_test.reshape(x_test.shape[0], x_test.shape[1],)
input_shape = (x_train.shape[1],)

# Convert class vectors to binary class matrices. This uses 1 hot encoding.
y_train_binary = keras.utils.to_categorical(y_train, num_classes)
y_test_binary = keras.utils.to_categorical(y_test, num_classes)
```

Now let's make our model. Here I do make the hidden layers have more neurons per layer.

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(32,
                 activation='relu',
                 input_shape=input_shape))
model.add(Dense(128, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax'))
model.compile(loss=keras.losses.categorical_crossentropy,
              optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adadelta(),
              metrics=['accuracy'])
```

Now we can train the model

```
epochs = 4
batch_size = 128
# Fit the model weights.
model.fit(x_train_reshaped, y_train_binary,
          batch_size=batch_size,
          epochs=epochs,
          verbose=1,
          validation_data=(x_test_reshaped, y_test_binary))
```

> 50000/50000 [==============================] - 3s 58us/step - loss: 1.6716 - acc: 0.4038 - val_loss: 1.6566 - val_acc: 0.4094

Comment: Thank you so much for the time and effort you have taken to help me out. I guess my main mistake is the model I have chosen (only 1 hidden layer with 100 neurons). But why did you reshape the input again here at "# Channels go last for TensorFlow backend" ? And how do you choose the optimal number of hidden layers and neurons in them? Are these hyperparams ?

Comment: @j.tribbiani, So the reason for the reshape is to set the channels as the last dimension. This is a requirement for the Keras library with TensorFlow backend, for Theano you would need to put the channels first. If you use the `model.summary()` you will be able to see how the neurons are set up. For the number of layers and number of neurons, these are indeed hyper parameters. Usually picked using cross-validation.